# Solvilocks and the 17 chars

Tags: pattern

**O**nce upon a time, a little user named Solvilocks
tramped into the woods and happened on a house
with three puzzles cooling on the windowsill
and nobody home.

The first puzzle was much too hard.   “Ow!”

The second puzzle simply seemed too easy.   Sneer.

*This* puzzle might turn out just right.

`Your name to begin` said the puzzle.

             
`Little Solvilocks`, typed little Solvilocks, and thought:
                                              (Too easy too?)

 `17 chars too many`          `?`
                                                            (Really?)

 `16 chars too many`          `really?!`

 `15 chars too many`          `?`

 `14 chars too many`          `this`

 `13 chars too many`          `is`

 `12 chars too many`          `silly`

 `11 chars too many`          `?`

 `10 chars too many`
              
`or`
 `9 chars too many`           `wha?`

 `8 chars too many`           `?`

 `7 chars too many`           `?`

 `6 chars too many`
              
`or`
 `Just right`                  
                                                        `just right?`
                                             (I hope, I hope, I hope.)

 `5 chars too many`           `just?!`

 `4 chars too many`           `!`

 `3 chars too many`           `-???`
                                             (Is *this* what it wants?)

 `2 chars too many`
              
`or`
 `1 char too many`       `why you...`

           
                                         `??`
        
               [  = blank ]

           
                                         `???`
        
               [  = blank ]

 `0 chars remaining`
              
`or`
 `1 char remaining`      `?????`

 `No chars remaining`         `??????????`

 `2 chars remaining`          `-`

 `3 chars remaining`          `must`

 `4 chars remaining`          `stop`

 `5 chars remaining`          `typing`

 `6 chars remaining`          `compulsively`

 `7 chars remaining`          `rrrrrrrr`

 `8 chars remaining`          `ohhhhh`
                                        (Hmmmmm;)   (mmmmmm.)

 `9 chars remaining`          
                                                                    (Whew!)
              [  = empty entry ]

**What would the puzzle say next?**
 
(And why did it say everything else?)


All relevant information is only in what the puzzle said.
Everything else includes just one weak hint
and a red herring.

Comment: Just for clarification, is the final entry supposed to be marked as `\`  \`` or `\`\``?

Comment: The ` ` is an empty entry and the statement now says so.
Sorry to be inaccurate, @boboquack,
but I couldn't get the system to parse a truly empty `` as intended. (I don't even know how you got  ` ` to look right in your comment.)

Comment: I just used escapes like this: `\\`\\``.

Comment: That's two `\`\`` `\\`\\`` mysteries solved already, boboquack, thank you!

Comment: Are each of the `17 chars too many` type messages produced as a response to what Little Solvilocks answered on the previous line (i.e. a question/answer --> new question interactive situation)?  Or did all the messages exist at the start (e.g. on a piece of paper) and Little Solvilocks just answered each one?

Comment: You'd be safe to follow your hunch, @YowE3K, about how little an effect little Solvilocks actually had on those messages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears to me that

> The messages are self-referential in that they describe the difference between the number of characters in the message itself and the line number (starting from 0). I can't explain the blank entries: maybe the setter didn't find a solution for those or it would make the puzzle too obvious?

So, for instance,

> "17 chars too many" is on line 0 and has 17 characters, so 17 too many.
>
>  For the lines marked with an or, the puzzle found more than one possibility. Take line 10: it's either "6 chars too many", which has 16 chars and therefore 6 too many, or "Just right", which has 10 characters, exactly what it should be.

The first thing to catch my eye were

> the lines with an "or" in them. If the answer changes depending on what the answer itself is, then surely something self-referential must be going on.
>
>  Since all of the lines talk about character counts, that is the natural suspicion, and one can easily notice that the "or" points are the points in which the character count changes (either because of two digits -> one digit or singular -> plural).

As for the blanks,

> I'm guessing this happens because there is no way to make a correct answer of the format "[number] chars too many", "Just right", or "[number] chars remaining" for those lines.
>
>  I do not like this because the rules as to what the puzzle might say don't seem so stringent at a first glance: it uses "no" instead of "0" in one of the lines, and the hint given in the community wiki uses "characters left" (if changing the wording is indeed illegal, that would be an evil red herring).

For the next line,

> If we assume the answer can only be in the format "[number] chars remaining", then we can't represent 27 characters that way, as "9 chars remaining" is 26 and "10 chars remaining" is 28. So that line would have to be a blank.

Summary table from puzzle’s poser:

> ```
>     Target cutoff                          Target length
>                 \                         ---------------
>                  \17 chars too many              0
>                  1\6 chars too many              1
>                  15\ chars too many              2
>                  14 \chars too many              3
>                  13 c\hars too many              4
>                  12 ch\ars too many              5
>                  11 cha\rs too many              6
>             or/  10 char|s too many              7 \
>               \  9 chars| too many               7 /
>                  8 chars \too many               8
>                  7 chars t\oo many               9
>             or/  6 chars to|o many              10 \
>               \  Just right|                    10 /
>                  5 chars too\ many              11
>                  4 chars too \many              12
>                  3 chars too m\any              13
>             or/  2 chars too ma|ny              14 \
>               \  1 char too man|y               14 /
>               x                 \               15 x
>               x                  \              16 x
>             or/  0 chars remaining|             17 \
>               \  1 char remaining |             17 /
>                  No chars remaining\            18
>                  2 chars remaining  \           19
>                  3 chars remaining   \          20
>                  4 chars remaining    \         21
>                  5 chars remaining     \        22
>                  6 chars remaining      \       23
>                  7 chars remaining       \      24
>                  8 chars remaining        \     25
>                  9 chars remaining         \    26
>               x                             \   27 x
>                  10 chars remaining          \  28
> ```

Comment: `11 chars too few` (and quite a few other alternatives) would suit the next response.  (P.S.  Given how long I have stared at this puzzle without having any inspiration, ffao certainly deserves the bounty!  [But, if someone explains the blanks as well ...?])

Comment: Ohh!! Ohh! Ohhh!  The next line could be `Well done Little Solvilocks` (or `Correct Little Solvilocks!!`, or maybe the owners of the house came back and said `Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrowl !!`).

Comment: You make this so fun, @YowE3K.
And indeed, `_ chars too few` was in the original draft,
partly as it's also the grammatically appropriate
inverse of `_ chars too many`.
The final format was chosen for clueliness, though,
and the resultant reason for blanks
is less interesting than imagined
and has already been touched on in this solution.

Comment: @humn Added a guess as to the blanks, as well as the reason why I did not suggest that initially. Also, feel free to the add the table to the answer.

Comment: The `581 characters left` hint was meant to be purely helpful for anyone who doesn't know how to experiment with chat profiles. Would it have been less misleading had it been labeled an _analogue_ or _parallel_ instead of an _equivalent_?  And yes, `Just right` is the worst inconsistency; the clues just seemed too flat without the suspicion-confirming dimension it adds.

Comment: @humn to be completely honest, had you labeled it an analogue I probably would have skipped over the word without actually paying attention to it. :) I'm more bothered by the "no chars" line, because if that is allowed than a bunch of other stuff could be, and it's not fully clear what, though I'm being a bit pedantic here. And of course the "Just right" line was very helpful to confirm, as you mentioned.

Comment: That was worth spending my rep. But I still can't understand the reason of "581 characters left" and "181 chars remaining". Can you add it in your answer please?

Comment: @manshu: https://puu.sh/tTWdX/8c5dabbee2.png

Comment: ah... very clever indeed

Answer (score 9):

(Wikified worksheet – feel free to correct or add.)

What the puzzle “said”
can be grouped like this,
with `or`s on the same lines.

```
                                                                  mostly
   consecutive         consecutive                              consecutive
     stretch             stretch             oddballs             stretch
 -----------------   ----------------   ------------------   -----------------
                                        Your name to begin
 17 chars too many
 16 chars too many
 15 chars too many
 14 chars too many
 13 chars too many
 12 chars too many
 11 chars too many
 10 chars too many   9 chars too many
                     8 chars too many
                     7 chars too many
                     6 chars too many   Just right
                     5 chars too many
                     4 chars too many
                     3 chars too many
                     2 chars too many   1 char too many
                                        [blank]
                                        [blank]
                                        1 char remaining     0 chars remaining
                                        No chars remaining
                                                             2 chars remaining
                                                             3 chars remaining
                                                             4 chars remaining
                                                             5 chars remaining
                                                             6 chars remaining
                                                             7 chars remaining
                                                             8 chars remaining
                                                             9 chars remaining
```

**From [manshu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17482/manshu):**

I found a hint on OP’s chat profile.
In about section, it says `181 chars remaining`:

[image]

> $\small\color{black}{\textsf{( From poser, a non-chat-profile equivalent if typed in a comment:}}$
>  `581 characters left`
>  $\small\color{black}{\textsf{)}}$

Comment: I wonder whether there is any significance in the fact that `Little Solvilocks` is 17 characters (including the space)?

Comment: To be fair, @YowE3K, that's the red herring, but noticing it is meant to be indirectly helpful nonetheless

Comment: Is the "weak clue" the "a different story altogether" comment?  Or is that another red herring?  :D

Comment: "Different story altogether" can be ignored. The weak clue is elsewhere, existing by accident rather than design, as the only even-remotely relevant detail outside this worksheet.

Comment: The tiny clue might be "This story is about that second puzzle." Which implies that this is not the puzzle itself but an explanation/story about the puzzle.

Comment: That premise would make for a mind-blowing `enigmatic-puzzle`, @stack reader! Not part of this puzzle, though - seems like a truly novel idea. Wow.

Comment: Maybe the tiny clue is the fact that the first letter O is made bold. 17+9=26 characters, exactly the number of letters in the alphabet. The clue could then be that it's keyboard related since the O is the ninth letter going from left to right, top to bottom (QWERTYUIO), and after the O there's 17 more to go.

Comment: Points for open-mindedness, @Levieux!  The **O** is bold just to imitate the way fairy tales, and many other writings, are printed.

Comment: Any ideas on why there is a "0" character's and a "no" chars yet?

Comment: Leading question (meant to help, though not too much), @mkinson, don't `0 chars remaining` and `No chars remaining` also seem `Just right`?

Comment: "Different story altogether" and "This story is about that second puzzle" have been edited out as they were completely extraneous artifacts of an initial insecurity about the difficulty level of this puzzle